# how to create a temporary file using threads in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, httphandler

i need to create a tmporary file (new.txt) in my Handler.ashx file,but the thing is i to save the created excel file in new.txt as temporary file.The problem is here i am hardcoded the temporary file as "new.txt".If more than one user access the same application what will happen.How to overcome from this problem.Can we use threading.

sample code..

```
 if (File.Exists(context.Server.MapPath("new.txt")))
            {
                File.Delete(context.Server.MapPath("new.txt"));
                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("new.txt"), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

            }
            if (!File.Exists(context.Server.MapPath("new.txt")))
            {

                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("new.txt"), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

            }

   string file = context.Server.MapPath("new.txt");
            byte[] myByte = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

            File.Delete(context.Server.MapPath("new.txt"));

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(myByte);
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.Close();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()` or `Path.GetRandomFileName()` method.

Comment: +1. They'd also want to change their logic to delete the file at the end of the operation, since the current approach of deleting it if it already exists will miss it as it'll be trying a different path to the previous run.